# Sync changes between directories using BASH

Tags: bash

### Sync changes between directories using BASH

Example Directories: 'Dir1' and 'Dir2'.

Example Files: 'example1.png' and 'example2.png'.

### Example of what I'd like to accomplish:

DIR1

- example1.png
- example2.png

DIR2

- EMPTY

## Copy DIR1 to DIR2

DIR1

- example1.png
- example2.png

DIR2

- example1.png
- example2.png

## The file called 'example2.png' was removed; Copy changes from the directory 'DIR1' to the directory 'DIR2'

DIR1

- example1.png

DIR2

- example1.png

## Tried:

### Copy all files from 'DIR1' to one directory outside of 'DIR1'

```
cp * ..
```

### Move all 'example.png' files to 'DIR2'

```
mv *example*.png DIR2
```

### Go to 'DIR1', remove 'example2.png' and go one directory outside of 'DIR1'

```
cd DIR1 && rm example2.png && cd ..
```

### I don't know what to do after this point.

Comment: `rsync` can do what you're after.  It's a complicated command, but there are lots of examples on the web.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I can give rsync a try. Do you have a specific example command I could try?

Comment: `rsync -var --delete DIR1/ DIR2/` is enough.  It will copy only the files that have changed, and the `--delete` flag will remove any files that were deleted from DIR1.

Comment: Thanks again! This worked for me. I am not sure how to mark this issue as solved.

Comment: @User you will be able to accept your own answer after 48 hours. Doing so will mark the question as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved:

```
rsync -var --delete DIR1/ DIR2/
```

Thank you for the help!

https://stackoverflow.com/users/1883316/tim-roberts